# How to make image resizable in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I try to find an API for resize image by drag like [resizable in jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) in iOS. 
The command  $("img").resizable(); only work with mouse gestures on desktop.

Please guide me how to make? 
This is [my code](https://github.com/lequysang/gitfiles02/blob/master/TestDragableInUIWebView.zip) load to UIWebView

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lot of libraries which convert touch events to mouse events for which we have binded functions. But i used [touch-punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and it met my needs. Even if you need resize or drag.

EDIT: BTW for resize you may need to increase the size of handles through CSS.

Comment: + 1, great find, since iOS doesn't actually support resize.